# Rewrite formula in terms of

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a homework question but I don't want the answer. I just want to know if I'm right or wrong to see if I understand what I'm doing.

Need to rearrange this in terms of d

$a = b \times c + b \times d$

My answer is:
$\frac{(a - bc)}{b} = d$

Is that correct?

If not any hints or resources would help.  I've used KhanAcademy which seems good.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes , It is correct

Comment: It is correct :).

Comment: Great thanks! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To close this question off with an answer
$$
a = bc +bd = bd + bc
$$
so lets try to make $d$ the subject by bringing everything to one side with the exception of the terms with $d$ in it.
$$
a - bc = bd + bc - bc = bd + 0 = bd
$$
now we have a term on the right hand side $b\times d$, and what is the opposite of multiplication? it is division so we can divide both sides by $b$ 
$$
(a-bc)\div b = (b\times d)\div b = d
$$
and then you are done
$$
\frac{a-bc}{b} = d
$$
now this is the result you require (and you correctly obtained so well done!!)
Now from my experience some students have an issue of seeing that 
$$
\frac{a-bc}{b} = d 
$$
is the same or equivalent to
$$
d = \frac{a-bc}{b}
$$
(just in case)